# Spacing between Images of a Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am a bootstrap rookie and my programming skills are very basic. I want to develop a small portfolio website with bootstrap. But I got stuck on a small problem: Is there a way to put a small gap of 10 px between each image of a bootstrap carousel?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome. You should post a MCVE. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Some useful resources for creating a MCVE. http://codepen.io/, https://jsfiddle.net, https://plnkr.co/

Answer (score 0):

**You can style the bootstrap classes directly.**

```js
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('item');

var timer = setInterval(function() {
  for(var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
    if(items[i].classList.contains('active')) {
      items[i].classList.remove('active');
      
      if(i+1 >= len) {
         items[0].classList.add('active');
      }
      else {
        items[i+1].classList.add('active');
      }
    }
    
  }
}, 3000);
```

```css
#carousel img {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placecage.com/1000/1000" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placecage.com/750/1000" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://placecage.com/gif/1000/1000" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! But the problem is a little bit more complicated. Yes, I want to put a a small gap of 10 px between each image. The thing is: The white space should only appear when the carousel gets to the next Slide. I could do it with "Slick Carousel" (you can see it here: http://timturiak.de/schmiedemuenks/testslider.html). Unfortunately the Plugin has some other disadvantages …